# Understanding the MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

Just a quick question. I have searched for a user group to post this in a more suitable location to no avail.

I am getting familiar with the MEAN stack: https://github.com/linnovate/mean

However I cannot see the reason for the separation into .jade templates under app/views, and .html under public.

Anyone know the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html files are static, they are delivered as is to the user, which is why they are stored in public folder. jade are templates, they are usually dynamically rendered (converted to html) per request. You can supply a data object (like user/session information) to templates to render html accordingly.

Comment: But in the MEAN stack Angular binding is used within the .html files under public - i.e, these pages are ultimately rendered (albeit client side) by angular's binding engine. I guess my intuition was the views could be kept private with access control and public files were not needed to be under control. However the example app actually put content that is always delivered (header/footer etc.) in the 'views' folder. I can understand why external libs (angular/bootstrap etc) are under public but they put application specific code there? I don't get it!

Comment: I have thought through your answer again. I can actually see some server side binding in some (not all) of the .jade templates. I'll give you the credit for the answer as it helped clear my thinking about this, although i think that access control is also important and can only be applied to the views folder.