# Understanding the mean stack and integrating uglify.js and stylus

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, stylus, uglifyjs, mean-stack

I'm just getting started with the MEAN stack (https://github.com/linnovate/mean), so I'm pretty sure my question is going to look very basic to an expert, so my apologies in advance!

While I think it would be a gread addition to what this stack already has to offer, I cannot manage to integrate `Uglify.js` and `stylus`

<strike>Also someone already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161088/understanding-the-mean-stack), but it would make sense to me to use **Jade** template for both server and public views, at least for a matter of standardization.</strike>

I have tried playing with the grunt file and `server.js`, renaming  some files, but all I managed to achieve so far, is break the original project...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Just found a fork of this project which has just added support for jade templates for public views: https://github.com/tutley/mean

Answer (score 2):

This post explains how to integrate Stylus pre-processing to the MEAN stack: http://to-s.tk/integrate-stylus-to-the-mean-stack/

Short version:

- Move `public/css` to a new `assets/stylesheets` and rename all the `.css` files to `.styl`
- Install `grunt-contrib-stylus` through `npm`'s `package.json`, as both a dev and runtime dependency.

-Configure stylus compilation in your Gruntfile

```
// ...
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
    watch: {
        // ...
        stylus: {
            files: ['assets/stylesheets/**/*.styl'],
            tasks: ['stylus']
        },
        // ...
    },
    // ...
    stylus: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                paths: ['assets/stylesheets/**']
            },
            files: [{
                dest: 'public/css/',
                cwd: 'assets/stylesheets/',
                src: '*.styl',
                ext: '.css',
                expand: true
            }]
        }
    },
    // ...
});
//...
//Load NPM tasks
// ...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');
// ...
```

- Import views stylus files (or any substylus) in `common.styl` using `@require` statements
- Remove references to views or other `substylesheets` in `head.jade`.

Then all `assets/stylesheets/*.styl` files should be automatically compiled into `public/css/*.css`, as long as `grunt` is running. To trigger a compile without relying on `watch`, you can run `grunt stylus`.